# Displaying Badges for Meta sites in Android app

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, android-app

In Android app, `All accounts` -> `All sites` page I can see the all sites name along with it's reputations. But the Badges are displaying only for main sites, not for Meta.

Its my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to display the Badges that are earned in Meta sites also in the Android app.

**Current view with out Badges for All sites.**

[image: All sites without Badges]

**Proposed view with Badges for All sites.**

[image: All sites with Badges]

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, I requested to show the earned Badges in the Meta sites to show it's relevant place holder (next to the Meta site's reputation), not the same badges from the Main sites.

Comment: @rene: This [query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site%3Bmain_site&filter=default&run=true) returns the Meta and Main site data. [Source](http://stackapps.com/q/6732/37357)

Comment: You're right but strangely enough the badge_count for your meta.stackoverflow is all zero's while it isn't on your actual profile. Looks like a bug in the API, not in the app.

Comment: @rene, not always all zeroes, but always the wrong counts.  See [the related bug report on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/6734/badge-numbers-are-wildly-erroneous-for-meta-accounts-returned-by-the-associated).

Comment: @AwesomePoodles So it is a bug in the API then, not in the app.

Comment: @rene, Yes, it looks that way.  But if someone can spot check some hi-activity users to see if the app shows *some* badges (occasionally) on meta sites, then that would help prove that conjecture.