# No badges for meta sites in the community list in the iOS app

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app, communities-list

I don't see any badge for any meta site in the community list in the iOS app:

> [image: no meta badges]

If you open user profile for such sites you will see actual badges count, e.g. ruSO.meta:

> [image: ruso meta]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: Related, but different: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299960/295232

Comment: Also, reproduced on v1.6.6.2. For me, Meta Stack Overflow *does* show badges, but it's one of my favourited sites.

Comment: @Glorfindel curious, we posted related bugs independently. I didn't see your post before.

Comment: Related for android-app [Displaying Badges for Meta sites in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271969/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar seems this's API specific bug.

Comment: @alexolut Yes. The [API for meta](https://stackapps.com/a/6733/37357) always return zero badges [/2.2/users/2855348/associated?types=meta_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#ids=2855348&types=meta_site&filter=default&run=true)